# Word for "had they not provided for us, we would have learned to provide for ourselves"

Tags: single-word-requests

In [a recent discussion about the license changes to Fusion 360](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24496090) a user mentioned that the existence of a "free" tool (no payment necessary) has precluded development of a "libre" tool ([a tool that the user can receive the source code for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)). I think that this is very insightful and pertinent to many actions we see [in software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish), [in politics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNRWA), and in other places in life.

**Is there a word that describes "had they not provided for us, we would have learned to provide for ourselves"?**

There is of course the positive and the negative connotation of the idea. Ideally I would like a word for each: one assuming **good intention** (such as a [helicopter parent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter_parent)) and another assuming **bad intention** (such as [Nestle providing milk supplements just long enough to hinder the production of breast milk](https://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/nestle-baby-milk-scandal-food-industry-standards)).

**My intention is to use the words in a convincing format: Don't take the fish, but rather learn to fish.**

If there are other angles, examples, alternate phrases, then I would appreciate being informed.

Comment: Please add 'phrases' / 'idioms' / 'proverbs' tags to fully  license 'alternate phrases'.

Comment: The modern brush-off for people who just want the ***answer*** (not interested in learning how to solve a problem for themselves) is [***gimme teh codez**.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308837/make-it-easier-to-close-job-shop-gimme-teh-codez-questions)

Comment: free and libre mean the same thing in different languages, so, frankly I have zero idea what you mean, including your attempted fishing metaphor.

Comment: @Lambie: I did not realize the need to clarify that I meant in English, at we are on the English.SE site. I apologize for the confusion. The fishing metaphor is [a quote](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime), I thought that it was well known. I've edited the title and question to remove the quote.

Comment: "libre" is not English and how that whole thing has anything at all to do with the fish thing is still not clear. **the existence of a "free" tool has precluded development of a "libre" tool**. = the existence of a "free" tool has precluded development of a "libre" [free]  tool. But everyone seems to be ignoring the **non sequitur**.

Comment: @Lambie: The term "libre", as used in the context of the question, means software that affords the user [certain rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). I (perhaps mistakenly) thought this to be a known usage of the term. I've added clarification to the question and additionally a link to more information. I appreciate you taking the time to explain to me how to ask a better question.

Answer (score 3):

The usual proverb covering your title statement is

**Necessity is the mother of invention.**

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/necessity_is_the_mother_of_invention) defines this proverb:

> - When the need for something becomes imperative, you are forced to find ways of getting or achieving it.

The implication, as you point out is the true situation, being that if there is no urgency, people become complacent and progress isn't made. New tools, methods, ideas are left undeveloped.

A more common phrasing of your title statement is [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)]

- Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: Thank you very much Edwin! Is there a single word for this type of situation?

Comment: I knew a group of wags who detailed proverbs, so this would have been 'Necessity is ...!' but I'm not aware of a one-word synonym. It's a lot of concept to squeeze into a single word. 'Pragmatical' (solving problems with what is to hand) has a related sense, though using the noun 'pragmatics' (the solving of problems thus) in this way is far rarer than using 'pragmatism' (the attirude)..